# EF6: generic DbConfiguration for different DbContexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I just updated from EF5 to EF6. This got me introduced to the DbConfiguration, since I needed one of these so that I wouldnt need to add EntityFramework as dependency to my other projects (solution has 8 projects).
Everything was working untill I decided to make my DbConfiguration class (inherited) to be generic, so that other DbContext classes could use it. After doing so, I started getting the error "Failed to create instance of type 'Repository.Contexts.ContextConfiguration`1[Repository.Contexts.GlobalContext]'. The type must not be generic.".

Heres the [new] DbConfiguration:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;

namespace Repository.Contexts
{
    // Old impl did not have a constraint. Instead, the type was directly used in the CreateDatabaseIfNotExists's param
    public class ContextConfiguration<TContext> : DbConfiguration where TContext : DbContext
    {
        public ContextConfiguration()
        {
            SetDatabaseInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<TContext>());
            SetProviderServices(SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, SqlProviderServices.Instance);
        }
    }
}
```

The configured is used as such:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

[DbConfigurationType(typeof(ContextConfiguration<GlobalContext>))]
public class GlobalContext : DbContext
{
    // DbSets...
    // Constructor...
    // OnModelCreating...
}
```

Do every context has to have its own configuration in order to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why you need the DbConfiguration? You have a seed method ?

Comment: @BassamAlugili without it, I was getting the "No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file." exception. Some posts said that, to fix this, I needed to include EntityFramework as reference to all the projects that uses my DAO project (as stated above).